# Why isn't java wrapper not picking up the right version specified in JAVA_HOME on macOS?

Tags: java, macos

Installed OpenJDK 14 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Unzipped and moved the folder under the JavaVirtualMachines folder.

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    14.0.1, x86_64: "OpenJDK 14.0.1"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_91, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home

$ printenv | grep JAVA
JAVA_14_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home

$ which java
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

Why is it still picking up the older version? All the answers I've read so far indicate that the /usr/bin/java should delegate to the JAVA_HOME value.
Maybe a fresh set of eyeballs can explain this.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

$ $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
openjdk version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably picking up Java from the PATH which hasn't changed just because you copied the SDK.

I heartily recommend using SDKMan (https://sdkman.io/). It will manage all this stuff for you - it's a great tool.

Comment: Great catch.. need to step away from the machine :)
An old line of `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME\bin:$PATH` in my .bash_profile was "baking in" the 1.8 path. It was always finding the 1.8 java first via the path. Removed the offending line - now switching the version via an alias works as expected!
For the ones who follow `which java` should output `/usr/bin/java`

Comment: Presto wouldn't work with Java 8 that I had installed.. installed 14 - which again wouldn't work. So had to install 11 - sdkman approach was a breeze compared to all the hoops I jumped to get 14 installed manually.